# Angular prod build generates wierd ERROR TypeError: t.url.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-cli

> core.es5.js:1020ERROR TypeError: t.url.toLowerCase is not a function
>       at t.XKz0.t.intercept (http://localhost:8080/vendor.ac754a60cfe780dcc3b3.bundle.js:1:558808)
>       at t.XKz0.t.handle (http://localhost:8080/vendor.ac754a60cfe780dcc3b3.bundle.js:1:553369)
>       at e.project (http://localhost:8080/vendor.ac754a60cfe780dcc3b3.bundle.js:1:551594)
>       at e._tryNext (http://localhost:8080/vendor.ac754a60cfe780dcc3b3.bundle.js:1:678138)
>       at e._next (http://localhost:8080/vendor.ac754a60cfe780dcc3b3.bundle.js:1:678040)
>       at e.T14+.e.next (http://localhost:8080/vendor.ac754a60cfe780dcc3b3.bundle.js:1:501673)
>       at e._subscribe (http://localhost:8080/vendor.ac754a60cfe780dcc3b3.bundle.js:1:582317)
>       at e.t._trySubscribe (http://localhost:8080/vendor.ac754a60cfe780dcc3b3.bundle.js:1:590816)
>       at e.t.subscribe (http://localhost:8080/vendor.ac754a60cfe780dcc3b3.bundle.js:1:590645)
>       at t.call (http://localhost:8080/vendor.ac754a60cfe780dcc3b3.bundle.js:1:677655)

Any idea, somebody had similar issue? Tracking stack trace does not give any clue what the source of the error is.

Of cource disabling `AOT` solves the issue.

Comment: had to figure out from this only thing to infer is have you used `toLowerCase` in your app some where

Comment: nowhere , unfortunately